# Android maps is cut off in a View Pager in Android 8

Tags: android, google-maps

Actually i have a View pager with 3 tabs, in the first fragment i have a container for insert the map, this is my xml fragment_store

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            ...
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_container_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                />
  </layout>
```

and this is my FragmentStoreActivity:

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ...

            mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.linear_layout_container_map, mapFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            return rootView;
        }

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_ubicacion_mapa);
        Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 115, 115, false);

        location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(branche.getCoordLat()), Double.parseDouble(branche.getCoordLong()));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(branche.getAddress())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, ZOOM_CAMERA_MAP));
        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
    }
```

All work fine, but in the verison to Android 8... when i swip the tabs the map cut off and the container turn black, if i turn off/on the screen the map recovery his normal shape

[Screen work ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8dQh.jpg)

[Swip of th taps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Ey8.jpg)

[Problem with the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weyeo.jpg)

Comment: I'ts in the fragment_store in the top of the post 
`<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_container_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                />`